# Wrap Text inside flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two div containers. The first container got a fixed with of 300px. The second div should fill the outer div. To solve this problem, I used flexboxes. My problem is now, that the second div don't wrap the content. How can I fix this problem?

[Here is a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XD8s/306/)

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left{
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
  flex-grow: 1;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Here is Some Text
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you can't use `float` inside flex container and the reason is that **float property does not apply to flex-level boxes**.

You should also remove `height` from `.right` item and use `flex: 1` instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">Here is Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not stupid you should just decide if you want to use flexbox or float

Comment: I think flexbox is the better solution. :P

Answer (score 3):

`float` does not affect flex-items...I think this is what you are after.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left{
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Here is Some Text
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! It solved my problem. I don't know, why I used float...